how can I design product card responsive with 2 columns and sequencially they besides one another and keep no gap?
I want a responsive product gallery where product will be shown with two columns in mobile view and there will be no gap between product cards as marked in the below image. css float property makes gaps and flex property grow and fill the gap and the products heights remain same. I want different products shown with different height and no gap between them. Please help me to do that. Thank you.
I code something but this is not the right way. It shows all products responsive but different height products will be flexed and not like the second image I mensioned.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive products</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container{
            width:96%;
            padding:5px;
            margin:50px auto;
            background-color: #eee;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .product-card{
            width:24%;padding:10px;margin-bottom:20px;background-color: #fff;border-radius:6px;box-shadow:3px 5px 8px #ddd;overflow:hidden;
        }

        .product-card img{
            width:100%;height:300px;object-fit: cover;
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
            .product-card{
                width:48%;
            }
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/CNCAKE13000001-A4Tech-Keyboard-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="title">A4Tech Keyboard</div>
            <div class="price">BDT 700</div>
            <div class="rating">****</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Electric-Motorcycle-for-2-7-years-old-Baby.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="title">Electric Motorcycle for 2-7 years old Baby</div>
            <div class="price">BDT 7500</div>
            <div class="rating">****</div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/CNCAMO10000001-A4Tech-Wired-USB-Mouse-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="title">A4Tech Wired USB Mouse</div>
            <div class="price">BDT 400</div>
            <div class="rating">****</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/CNCDAI28000001-ECCALL0001--91Unw6udhjL.-SY450-.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="title">All in One PC</div>
            <div class="price">BDT 32700</div>
            <div class="rating">****</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>

Full width with bigger screen
responsive design
I want this above design where products are besides with their height and remain no gap. I marked with red color. Please help me. Thank you in advance.
